# Negative Sampling Skip Gram model without one hot vector input

Tags: deep-learning, keras, word2vec

I have pairs of movie witch contains 2783 features. 
The vector is defined as: if the feature is in the movie it's 1 otherwise it's 0.
Example :

```
movie 1 = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1 ...] & movie 2 = [1,0,1,1,1,0,1 ...]
```

Each pair has for label 1 or 0.

```
movie1,movie2=0
movie1,movie4=1
movie2,movie150=0
```

The input is similar to SGNS (Skip gram negative sampling) word2vec model.
My goal is to find similarity between programs and learn embedding of each movie. 
I'd to build a kind of 'SGNS implementation with keras'. However my input is not one hot and I can't use the Embedding layers. I tried to use Dense layers and merge them with a dot product. I'm not sure about the model architecture and I got errors.

```
from keras.layers import Dense,Input,LSTM,Reshape
from keras.models import Model,Sequential

    n_of_features = 2783
    n_embed_dims = 20

    # movie1 vectors
    word= Sequential()
    word.add(Dense(n_embed_dims, input_dim=(n_words,)))

    # movie2 vectors
    context = Sequential()
    context.add(Dense(n_embed_dims, input_dim=n_words,))

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(keras.layers.dot([word, context], axes=1))

    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                  loss='mean_squared_error')
```

If someone has an idea how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not wedded to Keras, you could probably model this by turning each movie into a synthetic 'document' with tokens for each feature-that-is-present. Then, use a 'Paragraph Vectors' implementation in pure PV-DBOW mode to learn a vector for each movie.

(In pure PV-DBOW, dense doc-vectors are learned to predict each word in a document, without regard to order/word-adjacency/etc. It is a bit like skip-gram, but the training pairs are not 'word to every nearby word' but 'doc-token to every in-doc word'.)

In gensim, the Doc2Vec class with initialization parameter `dm=0` uses pure PV-DBOW mode.

Comment: Hi @gojomo
Thanks for your answer. I don't want the model to learn skip gram pairs between feature but between item vectors.
What will be the doc2vec input ? It's the sequence of two movie feature and the label is 1 or 0 ?

Comment: If your aim is to learn a vector-per-movie, and (if all works well) for the similarities of these vectors to reflect the similarities of the movies, then the setup I described – documents (`TaggedDocument` class in gensim) for each movie, each document containing tokens-per-feature, PV-DBOW mode – will likely work. The skip-gram-like pairs in that case will always be (movieN)->(featureM), but still tend to arrange the various movieN vectors based on common-features. (It might also in such a case be useful to encode absence-of-feature as a `not-featureM` token, I'm not sure.) [cont'd]

Comment: If you need something SGNS-like but with just (movieN)->(movieM) pairs, I'm not sure what to do with your 0-valued pairs, because SGNS only takes as input positive (existing-in-the-text) pairs. (It synthesizes random negative examples – which might occasionally collide with positive examples but in the end that noise doesn't hurt much.) But you could shoehorn your positive pairs into Word2Vec training: turn all such pairs into short pseudosentences like `['movie1', 'movie4']`, etc. After running all those 'sentences' through, the 'movieN' tokens may learn the kind of vectors you seek.

Comment: Hi @gojomo. Actually I already built all my label movie pairs (positive and negative). It's positive if the user has watched the two movie and negative if he only watched one. I just need to construct a model that will learn either two movie are watched or not; Like word2vec SGNS which learn either two words are close or not.

Comment: Why not reproduce kind of word2vec SGNS model but instead of one hot words vector and one hot word context representation. It will be a sparse vector for each movie where it's 1 if the feature is in the movie and 0 otherwise. The architecture is really similar. I thought about using two denser layer (one for movie 1 representation and the second for movie2 representation), merge them with the dot product and and add another dense layer for the label.

Comment: #Model example 
models = []
#Word vectors
model_word = Sequential() 
model_word.add(Dense(300, input_shape=(1,2000)))
model_word.add(Reshape((300,)))
models.append(model_word)
 Context vectors
model_context = Sequential()
model_context.add(Dense(300, input_shape=(1,2000)))
model_context.add(Reshape((300,)))
models.append(model_context)
#Combined model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Merge(models, mode='dot', dot_axes=1))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam').

Comment: What do you think about it, I took information from https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1787

Comment: You're improvising other custom NN models here, about which I have no opinion. My suggestions are ways to re-cast your data in a way that looks more like standard word2vec/paragraph-vectors, so it can be fed into off-the-shelf standard-NN implementations like those in Python gensim. (I think that's a simpler approach that may offer the same benefits, or more because it'll allow you to experiment with more variants in the same amount of time as it'd take for you to get a custom vaguely-like-SGNS-but-not-really model working.)